# Ipad uisplitviewcontroller - how to set and call the masterviewcontroller table reload data from detail

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm using an iPad UISplitviewcontrol with master on left and detail on right.
On master, I have a NSMutableArray *data, and call self.data = myarraydata, and call self.tableview reloaddata and works, and when a row on master is clicked, data is passed to detail on right without any problem.

However, from the detail side, I want to set the master's self.data to a different array, and call the master's reload data method.  I've read up on delegates, and traversing up the navigation tree to get to the master's table object but no luck.

Can any help provide sample or clips on how can I achieve this?

TIA.